# struct declaration in C++ Builder XE4

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-xe4

I tried the following code in C++ Builder XE4.

As I recall, struct type name can be used as type (no need to add "struct"
in the variable declaration).

However, C++ Builder XE4 outputs compile error for pt1 declaration.

```
struct Point {
    int x, y;
};


void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Point pt1; // error ( E2379 Statement missing ; )

    struct Point pt2;   // no error
}
```

The same code can be compiled without error on Ideone.com
http://ideone.com/kVzrlc

Is the C++ Builder implementation of C++ struct somewhat different?

Comment: Make sure you are compiling as C++ and not as C. It may depend on the filename.

Comment: Always paste the actual error into the question, do not place in comments of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++Builder **Point** is a function has been defined in **Classes.hpp**. You should change your struct name (like TMyPoint) or use **struct** keyword in this case.

*Note*: In BCB you can use predefined and already accessible types for storing point data such as **POINT**, **TPoint**, ...

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't recognize that the "Point: has been defined in C++ Builder. It worked after I changed the name "Point" into others.